# getting back list view position from Activity C to Activity B then to proceed

Tags: android

I have a list view in class called A and if i press any of the list item it will goes to page B, in page B i have some other elements and in Activity B i also have alert box, so if i select submit from that alert box it will take me to page C . so my question is i am taking list item position from Activity  A  to B using Bundles but in Activity C  if i clicks on back button and then again if i clicks on submit button in alert box in Activity B  its showing error that its not going to Activity C. I searched in google and i implemented but its not working....so can any one help me please....
A Activity is

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1 = 0;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2 = 1;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT = 2;

private static final int LIST_ITEM_COUNT = 3;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT = 1;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2_COUNT = 2;
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    //actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    // actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
        if (i < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("item type 1");
        else if(i==LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("Wbs for osting Booking");
        else
            mAdapter.addItem("Jake Johnson");
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1;
        else
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch(type) {
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_first_row, null);
                break;
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_sec_row, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.emp_nametxt);
                holder.textVersion = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.emp_idtxt);
                holder.img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
                holder.textVersion.setText("1.100235");
                holder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("pos",""+ position);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public TextView textVersion;
    public ImageView img;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    return true;
}
```

}

and my Activity B is

public class MenuActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1 = 0;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2 = 1;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3 = 2;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_4 = 3;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT = 4;

private static final int LIST_ITEM_COUNT = 4;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT = 1;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2_COUNT = 2;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3_COUNT = 3;

private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
        if (i < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("Jake JohnSon");
        else if(i<LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("ITEM TYPE 2");
        else if(i<LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("ITEM TYPE 3");
        else 
            mAdapter.addItem("ITEM TYPE 4");
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1;
        else if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2_COUNT)
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2;
        else if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3_COUNT)
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3;
        else 
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch(type) {
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_sec_row, null);
                holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.emp_nametxt);
                holder.textVersion = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.emp_idtxt);
                holder.img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                holder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
                holder.textVersion.setText("1.100235");
                break;
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_after_page_row2, null);
                holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.textView.setText("Absent");
                holder.text=(Switch)convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                break;
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_details_row3, null);
                break;
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_4:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_details_row4, null);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public TextView textVersion;
    public Switch text;
    public ImageView img;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==1)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //String name = data.getStringExtra("Result");
            Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
            String s=b.getString("pos");
            Intent i=new Intent(MenuActivity.this,EmpSignOffAfterPageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("pos", s);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case android.R.id.home:   
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        break;
    case R.id.action_settings1:

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MenuActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater =  MenuActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        alertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_window, null));
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Submit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
                String s=b.getString("pos");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item"+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(MenuActivity.this,EmpSignOffAfterPageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("pos", s);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
        return true;        
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and my Activity C is

public class EmpSignOffAfterPageActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1 = 0;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2 = 1;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3 = 2;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_4 = 3;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT = 4;

private static final int LIST_ITEM_COUNT = 4;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT = 1;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2_COUNT = 2;
private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3_COUNT = 3;

private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
        if (i < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("item type 1");
        else if(i<LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("ITEM TYPE 2");
        else if(i<LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("ITEM TYPE 3");
        else 
            mAdapter.addItem("ITEM TYPE 4");
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1;
        else if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2_COUNT)
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2;
        else if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3_COUNT)
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3;
        else 
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch(type) {
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_sec_row, null);
                holder.img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                holder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_agter_page_row1, null);
                break;
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_3:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_after_page_row2, null);
                break;
            case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_4:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_after_page_row2, null);
                holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.textView.setText(" Do you understand the hazards you may have been exposed to throughout your work day(falls,crush points,chemicaals,etc)?");
                holder.text=(Switch)convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public TextView textVersion;
    public Switch text;
    public ImageView img;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.emp_sign_off_after_page, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case android.R.id.home:   
        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        String s=b.getString("pos");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item"+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i=new Intent();
        i.putExtra("pos", s);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.action_settings1:     
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                EmpSignOffAfterPageActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater =  EmpSignOffAfterPageActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        alertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_sign_off_last_dialog, null));
        final EditText pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Approve",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
                String s=b.getString("pos");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item"+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(EmpSignOffAfterPageActivity.this,EmpSignOffLastPageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("pos", s);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Reject",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
                String s=b.getString("pos");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item"+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(EmpSignOffAfterPageActivity.this,EmpSignOffRejectActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("pos", s);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
        return true;        
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

so please tell how to take list item position back from Activity C to B, then if i clicks submit on alert box in B it should go to Activity C with list item position.....

Comment: I think your problem will be solved if instead of get `pos` in `setPositiveButton` get that in `onCreate` method and save that in one value.

Answer (score 0):

In your B Activity which is MenuActivity: in onActivityResult

replace it :

```
 Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
```

with :

```
 Bundle b=data.getExtras();
```

// onActivityResults has already result from returned activity. if you check by getIntent() then it would not have the reference of that activity.

Also when you click from dialog add null check in Intent as now you came back from C activity and don't have reference of that intent. You can set a bool if came from C activity then get the data of onActivityResult intent.